# Diff over large subdirectories fails

Tags: terminal, folders, file, firewire

I'm comparing two large directories on two different external FireWire 800 disks using

```
diff -r /path/to/directory1 /path/to/directory2
```

The size of the directory (and its subdirectories) on one FireWire disk is 118.2 GB for 30,000 items and 119.56 GB for 30,031 items.

I was surprised about the many differences reported in the output, like

```
Binary files /path/to/directory1/with/subdirectory/file_xyz and /path/to/directory2/with/subdirectory/file_xyz differ
```

and started comparing some of them individually. When I compare them with

```
diff /path/to/directory1/with/subdirectory/with/subdirectory/file_xyz /path/to/directory2/with/subdirectory/with/subdirectory/file_xyz
```

or even

```
diff  /path/to/directory1/with/subdirectory/ /path/to/directory2/with/subdirectory/
```

`diff` doesn't report any differences between these files or directories.

**What could be a reason why the "large comparison" reports so many differences (or seemingly fails), while the smaller chunk comparison doesn't?**

Edits since original post:

1. The version of `diff` I'm using is GNU diffutils 2.8.1.
2. Just a wild guess here, but could it have something to do with the fact that these directories are on external hard drives that could experience some sort of timeout?
3. I ran another comparison and was again presented with lots of differences between those directories. I then set the system preference's *Energy Saver* to not set the display to sleep for 1 hour, because I had measured with `time diff -r /path/to/directory1 /path/to/directory2` that it takes between 45 and 50 minutes for the diff to finish. My hard drives and the Mac never go to sleep.
   I then unmounted both drives and remounted them. Ran the diff again and voilà no differences found apart from one file. I manually compared that one reported differing file and found it to be identical.
   This seems to confirm what I found by comparing smaller chunks before. It also seems to confirm that there is something going on with a timeout as previously suspected, but I still wonder that *if* a FireWire drive would become unavailable or whatever, diff should not report a difference, but rather say "file not available" or "Only in /yada/yada/directory: file_xyz".
   Interestingly, the diff before the remount took 28 minutes, after the remount it took almost 51 minutes.
   In the light of that: *What can I do to prevent something like that from happening?*
   Of course one could say to never set the display to go to sleep or whatever, but that hardly seems to solve the underlying issue. Something else must be going on, I just can't figure out what.
   As an aside, on previous other occasions, after some time of inactivity on those FireWire hard drives I was trying to write to a file and got this *error code -50" message (mind you I didn't see any of that during the diff operation). I could always "resolve" the issue by unmounting and remounting the drives, but I believe there must be an entirely different solution to that:
   [image: Error Code -50 appears during write operation after external hd inactive for a while]
   Solutions [like those presented here](https://www.slideshare.net/CarmenPomes/fix-mac-error-code-50) hardly seem to be tackling the underlying problem.

Comment: are you looking for us to speculate that large data structures make trivial diff to choke? At some point, thousands of things will choke any tool. Or is this about finding a tool that can break up a large job?

Comment: @bmike Thousands of things should definitely not choke diff. It has been used for decades comparings huge number of files - I would definitely not expect it to be buggy when comparing thousands of files.

Comment: @bmike Not looking for speculations, but possible reasons, experiences or maybe even a solution in the use of diff. I haven't thought about breaking up a large job (yet) because as jksoegaard says I've been under the impression that diff should be able to handle things like that. I'm not doing petabytes of comparisons on millions of files. // I'll add some more thoughts to the post in the hope that it won't be considered as having too many questions...

Comment: I would poke around diffutils  source code for a CHANGELOG file which may have clues to a bug that was fixed.

Comment: @fd0 I had a look on the Gnu and downloaded the latest version 3.6 from http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/diffutils/, but interestingly there wasn't a CHANGELOG file that came with it. I also found this one, but couldn't really see anything that'd address the issue I encounter: https://fossies.org/linux/misc/diffutils-3.6.tar.xz/diffutils-3.6/ChangeLog. // From your experience could my issue be somewhat related to the two directories being on two exteral HDs?

Comment: have you actually visually compared any of the different and identical files to confirm what diff is returning? or is that possible?

Comment: @john I did. Though reported as different many of them are in fact identical.  I have run another test yesterday and will update above with my findings in a moment.

Comment: I found this posting to address the *error code -50* issue: https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/89252/error+code+-50+on+added+second+HDD (Select the "Answered! View the answer" button). I have now enabled "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" and will have to see if this also solves the issue with `diff` – though I'm still confused as to why diff would report differences when it simply can't write, as was the case with my *error code -50* on other occasions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a week I've tested a [recommended solution](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/89252/error+code+-50+on+added+second+HDD) I found at iFixit, when someone encountered an *error code -50* on an external HD. It seems to resolve the issue I had. I also came across *error code -50* before when I tried copying files across, but didn't immediately link this to my issue of failing diffs. I had the suspicion that some inactivity on the external hard drives was responsible for the failure and the article seems to confirm that. To quote from there for the solution should you run into similar problems:

> To work around this error you'll want to go into System Preferences->Energy Saver and for both Battery and Power Adapter tick the box next to "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" on your computer. Yes that means the OS will put all of your drives to sleep when it can but that's the only way I've found to fix the problem.
>
> What seems to happen is that some external drives have firmware which detects inactivity and spins the drives down. If OSX is not configured with the energy saver setting mentioned above then OSX is not expecting the drives to go to sleep. When accessing the drive after it puts itself to sleep obviously something gets messed up and the error -50 is thrown among other problems.
>
> By configuring the OS to put disks to sleep the OS will issue spin-up commands.

The one thing that puzzles or surprises me though is why `diff` would report actual differences in files, when in fact it couldn't access(?) the file properly.